# Change icon opacity when hover(symbol layer), in Mapbox GL JS

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I see in the documentation that icon-opacity supports feature-state,
https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/layers/#paint-symbol-icon-opacity

Therefore I use this code for making a change of opacity when user hovers over a icon:

```js
map.addLayer({
    type: 'symbol',
    layout: {
        'icon-image': 'point',
        ...
     },
     paint: {
         'icon-opacity':  
             ['case', ['boolean', ['feature-state','hover'], false], 1, 0.3]
     }
});
```

The problem is that it takes the original opacity right(0.3) but does not change on hover.

Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: When i edited your code it occurred to be a `}` was missing. Maybe Javascript put down some weird behavior because of this. Check that first

Comment: It is copied, thats not the problem, the code runs without errors, just happened the description above. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code you´re posting is right, but it's only half of the solution.

You already implemented the definition of the layer paint behavior for any feature (by default 0.3 as you say), the second part is to change the feature-state hover to true on mouseover.

The state of the features on 'hover' in your symbol layer don´t change automatically, you need to change it to true in a `map.on('mousemove', 'youLayerId'...` method, and again to false in a `map.on('mouseout', 'youLayerId'...` .

Check out this fiddle I have created for you on [how to change opacity of an icon](https://jsfiddle.net/jscastro76/g0hzdyr1/20/).
[image]

The relevant code is below

```js
        mapboxgl.accessToken = 'PUT HERE YOUR TOKEN';
        var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
          container: 'map',
          style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11'
        });
        let fHover = null;
        map.on('load', function() {
          map.loadImage(
            'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/7c/201408_cat.png',
            function(error, image) {
              if (error) throw error;
              map.addImage('cat', image);
              map.addSource('point', {
                'type': 'geojson',
                'generateId': true,
                'data': {
                  'type': 'FeatureCollection',
                  'features': [{
                    'type': 'Feature',
                    'geometry': {
                      'type': 'Point',
                      'coordinates': [0, 0]
                    }
                  }]
                }
              });
              map.addLayer({
                'id': 'points',
                'type': 'symbol',
                'source': 'point',
                'layout': {
                  'icon-image': 'cat',
                  'icon-size': 0.25,
                },
                'paint': {
                  'icon-opacity': [
                    'case',
                    ['boolean', ['feature-state', 'hover'], false],
                    1,
                    0.3
                  ]
                }
              });
            }
          );

          map.on('mousemove', 'points', function(e) {
            if (e.features[0]) {
              mouseover(e.features[0]);
            } else {
              mouseout();
            }

          });

          map.on('mouseout', 'points', function(e) {
            mouseout();
          });

          function mouseover(feature) {
            fHover = feature;
            map.getCanvasContainer().style.cursor = 'pointer';

            map.setFeatureState({
              source: 'point',
              id: fHover.id
            }, {
              hover: true
            });
          }

          function mouseout() {
            if (!fHover) return;
            map.getCanvasContainer().style.cursor = 'default';
            map.setFeatureState({
              source: 'point',
              id: fHover.id
            }, {
              hover: false
            });
            fHover = null;

          }
        });
```

Important, to change a feature state every feature must have an id in the source, so I strongly recommend to set always `'generateId': true` in the `addSource` method.

PS.- If this answer solves your question, please mark it as **answer accepted**, in that way it will also help other users to know it was the right solution.

Comment: I see, thank you very much! what is the reason not being required the extra event handling when the event is 'clicked'?

Comment: Glad it was helpful! It´s not an extra event handling, the definition you´re doing is to define a feature-state at the layer level for all the features, that doesn´t create any event handling, just the creation of a state. Then you have to make change that state value for one or many features based on your premises, indeed you could define many feature-states such as 'selected', 'clicked' and develop the custom behaviors you have.

Comment: Aha I see... it has to be set manually the state and feature-state mechanism will apply the defined feature change, thanks for your explanation.